# How to set password in my local database .mdf file C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a `.mdf` database file created with Visual Studio 2012. I want to secure my database with a password but I don't find a way to do that, please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: you should use `Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)` I think on your SQL database

Comment: You **cannot** just simply "add a password" to a SQL Server `.mdf` database file - such a feature just doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot secure a *.mdf file with a password just like that.

If you want to add more security to your solution consider adding an encryption mechanism to your application and then just encrypt/decrypt the file before the first connection to the DB is made.